# “Deliberately” vs. “intentionally” vs. “on purpose”

Tags: differences, adverbs, formality

I wonder if there is any difference between usage of these three:

- deliberately
- intentionally
- on purpose

Are they completely interchangeable? Are they at the same level of formality?

I found some explanation (forums) Googling the three words, but I don’t find them reliable since people simply stated their own opinion.

In the dictionary, they are mentioned as synonymous: *deliberately* means *intentionally*, and *on purpose* means *deliberately*.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The levels of formality are, in descending order: *intentionally*, *deliberately*, and *on purpose*. If you look at published books and journals that have blank pages, you'll find some with printed statements "This page **intentionally** left blank". That's because it's the most formal and the most neutral. Yes, *deliberately* is a synonym that means *intentionally*, but it more often has a negative connotation than *intentionally* does (especially among high school students, at least that was true when I was in high school), although both words are used both positively and negatively, e.g., *That was {a deliberate / an intentional snub}* (negative use, and [Google Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=intentional%20snub,deliberate%20snub&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) shows more frequent use of the former than the latter). Maybe that's merely because *deliberately* is more frequently used than *intentionally* is.

Wikipedia has an article on *[deliberate practice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Practice_%28learning_method%29)*, however, which shows that word's very positive connotation. There are also Web pages for *[intentional practice](http://www.wisdompage.com/practicing.html)* that show its equally positive connotation. [Google Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=intentional%20practice,deliberate%20practice&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) shows that *deliberate practice* is more often used than *intentional practice*. *On purpose* is what children say for *intentionally* and *deliberately*, which is why it's the at the lowest level of formality of those three terms. They are not always interchangeable: register and context must be taken into account.

Answer (score 14):

They are synonyms, which as with all synonyms means there is a slight difference in nuance (no two words are exactly identical).

*Intentionally* and *on purpose* differ mainly in register. *Deliberately* also carries another meaning of doing something with great care (compare *deliberated*), which while not necessarily implied in the sense you are talking about, does colour the word.

So, you can use any of them to convey the same meaning, but you might consider those subtle differences when aiming for the perfect choice in more considered writing.

Comment: This is a better answer, in that it explains the connotations a bit better. I'd go a step further, though, and differentiate "intentionally" and "on purpose."  
  
"On purpose" is generally antonymic to accidental: "You did that on purpose!"   
  
Intentional, on the other hand, implies forethought.

Comment: @TechWriter James: Both answers differentiate "intentionally" and "on purpose": Jon Hanna specifies that they differ **in register** and I imply precisely the same thing when I say that **children use "on purpose" rather than "intentionally" and "deliberately"**.

Comment: @Bill Franke: I must have missed your reference to children when I read your answer - apologies. On the register issue: I thought register referred to formality or audience, and my contention is that the difference goes beyond "children use this; adults don't" into the realm of nuances of meaning regardless of audience. Thus the two-part question: **Are they completely interchangeable? Are they at the same level of formality?** You answered the formality aspect; I thought the connotations addressed the interchangeability portion.

Comment: @TechWriter James: As with most linguistics terms, there are [different definitions of the term _register_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_(sociolinguistics)). The original (1956) seems to be the one I use: it categorizes by age. None of the three is completely interchangeable with the other two. Just as "I have to do number 2 would be inappropriate for talking with adults" because it's strictly children's lingo, "I did it intentionally" isn't appropriate for children because it's a 5-syllable word".

Comment: Even my 16-year-old Taiwanese son told me last night that he doesn't know the two words _intentionally_ & _deliberately_, but he does know _on purpose_. Yes, he's a native speaker of English, but that doesn't mean he speaks like a typical 16-year-old American high school junior: I have to use easy language with him, & I have to define formal terms if I use them. Just last night, e.g, he told me that he'd scored poorly on an English test because it required him to translate _English words with too many letters_ into Chinese. He doesn't know the term _big words_.

Answer (score -2):

To add to these responses from an etymological angle, '***deliberately***' uses a *weighing* metaphor, while '***intentionally***' uses a *stretching* metaphor.

Comment: How do you figure that?

Comment: I can see deliberation—in a judicial or juristic context—as retaining the sense of weighing implicit in the Latin root _libra_. But I don't think that much of that sense remains in the "intentional" sense of _deliberate_. And i don't see any appreciable survival of original "stretching out" sense of the Latin root _intentus_ in the modern English usage of _intentional_. Beware of the [etymological fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymological_fallacy).

Comment: @Sven Yargs I don't believe the Good Professor ever came back on 'Are dead metaphors still metaphors?'. Though I agree that if they're dead and buried, it's pointless trying to deduce modern connotations from their origins.

Comment: This answer needs independence, elaboration and references. I think the 1913 Webster's Dictionary's entries for [deliberate](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?action=search&word=deliberate&resource=Webster's) and [intent](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?action=search&word=deliberate&resource=Webster's) might show how these metaphors have survived. [Weigh](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/weigh)ing considerations is a metaphor we still use and is a core component of doing something deliberately at least. It could be said that intentions give the mind a [bent](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bent) too.